# How to update a VSI add-in to VSIX?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, vsix, vsinstaller

I currently have to update an outdated VSI add-in to the new VSIX architecture. The old VSI add-in runs on Visual Studio 2013 but not on Visual Studio 2015. Therefore I have to somehow "convert" the VSI add-in to VSIX.

Has anyone ever done something like this. I have no clue how I can do that. Every tiny help would be very appreciated!